# Multiple filters on DataGridView and null values

Tags: c#, datagridview

So I have a datagridview with many columns, two of which are 'Status', and 'Allocated To'. I have two fields where the user should be able to filter all the rows depending on what they type. My code looks like this:

```
status = textBox1.Text;
allocated = textBox2.Text;

BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = customerDataGridView.DataSource;

bs.Filter = "[Status] LIKE '%" + status + "%' AND [AssignedTo] LIKE '%" + allocated + "%'";
customerDataGridView.DataSource = bs;
```

This works well if the user has entered both a status and allocation, as it will find all records with both those filters. However, if one of the filters is left blank, so say Status = "Pending" and Allocation = "", it will filter the records as expected, so it will filter all fields where Status is Pending and where Allocated is empty. The problem is that, if the user was to leave Allocated empty, I would prefer it will just ignore this field in the filter and simply filter all Pending records irrespective of allocation.

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Edit: I should mention that I have included only two filters here for simplicity. My program actually has 6 filters, so the filter string takes 6 parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    status = textBox1.Text;
    allocated = textBox2.Text;

    BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
    bs.DataSource = customerDataGridView.DataSource;

   var filt = "";


    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(status))
       {
         if(filt == "")
            filt  += "[Status] LIKE '%" + status + "%'";
         else
            filt += " And [Status] LIKE '%" + status + "%' ";
       }


      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(allocated))
           {
             if(filt == "")
                filt  += "[AssignedTo] LIKE '%" + allocated + "%'";
             else
                filt += " And [AssignedTo] LIKE '%" + allocated + "%' ";
           }

         if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(param3))
          {
             if(filt == "")
                filt  += "[param3] LIKE '%" + param3+ "%'";
             else
                filt += " And [param3] LIKE '%" + param3+ "%' ";
          }

     bs.Filter = filt ;
    customerDataGridView.DataSource = bs;
```

and so on..

this example is only with 3 parameters, u can add more parameters, all u need to do is just "add more filter in filt variable before set it to bs.filter".
hope u get the idea.

Comment: Yes this is the same method S. Jerk suggested in his comment. This seems like the best way to go. Thanks for the working example!

Answer (score 1):

How about a if-clause then?

```
    string filterString = ""

    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(status)){
            filterString += "[Status] LIKE '%" + status + "%'";
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(allocated){
        if(!string.isNullOrEmpty(filterString) filterString += " AND ";
        filterString += "[AssignedTo] LIKE '%" + allocated + "%'";
    }
```

Comment: Yes I considered that, but in actuality there are about 6 fields that the user can fill out to filter, not just the two I mentioned here. I just mentioned two for simplicity. So if there's 6 fields, I would have to have an if clause of 36 conditions to cover for every possibility. This would work, but I was hoping there was an easier way to achieve the same result.

Comment: @nerdalert true that. And if you make an if-clause for every field and add the piece of the filter to a "filterString" and in the end set the filter to that string?

Comment: That seems like it could work well! I'll give that a try and report back.

Comment: I accepted Hendra Lim's answer since it has a working solution, so that other people who view this question will see the working code. I wish I could accept two answers since you had the idea first though, but thanks anyway!

Comment: I'm ok with that. I was too lazy to do the whole thing :D

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
status = textBox1.Text;
allocated = textBox2.Text;

BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = customerDataGridView.DataSource;

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(status) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(allocated))
    bs.Filter = "[Status] LIKE '%" + status + "%' AND [AssignedTo] LIKE '%" + allocated + "%'"; // both filter assign.
else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(status))
    bs.Filter = "[AssignedTo] LIKE '%" + allocated + "%'"; // only allocated filter assign.
else //(string.IsNullOrEmpty(allocated))
    bs.Filter = "[Status] LIKE '%" + status + "%'"; // only status filter assign.

customerDataGridView.DataSource = bs;
```

Comment: I updated my post with an edit. So although this will work well, you understand I will need 36 clauses I believe.